# Update of many rows with join extremely slow

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update, common-table-expression

I have a table with five relevant fields - `id`, `source`, `iid`, `track_hash`, `alias`. I want to group all entries into groups with a common `track_hash` and then for each row save the `id` of the row with the lowest `source` (with ties broken in favor of the highest `iid`) entry from its group into the `alias` field. To do this I wrote the following query:

```
with best as 
(SELECT id as bid, track_hash FROM
    (SELECT id, track_hash,
        RANK () OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY track_hash
            ORDER BY source asc, iid DESC
        ) rank
        from albums
    )
    where rank = 1
)
select bid, a.* from albums a inner join best
on a.track_hash = best.track_hash
```

This takes a completely reasonable 2 seconds on 24k rows. Now, instead of simply seeing this `id`, I want to actually save it. For this, I used the following very similar query:

```
with best as 
(SELECT id as bid, track_hash FROM
    (SELECT id, track_hash,
        RANK () OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY track_hash
            ORDER BY source asc, iid DESC
        ) rank
        from albums
    )
    where rank = 1
)
update albums
set alias = bid FROM albums a inner join best
on a.track_hash = best.track_hash
```

However, this one takes anywhere between 1 and 10 minutes, and I really don't understand why. Doesn't the engine have to match every row to its `best.id`/`alias` anyway, which is exactly what I'm doing with my update? Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

Query plan looks like this:

```
MATERIALIZE 1
CO-ROUTINE 4
SCAN TABLE albums USING INDEX track_hash_idx
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR RIGHT PART OF ORDER BY
SCAN SUBQUERY 4
SCAN TABLE albums USING COVERING INDEX track_hash_idx
SEARCH SUBQUERY 1 USING AUTOMATIC PARTIAL COVERING INDEX (rank=?)
SEARCH TABLE albums AS a USING COVERING INDEX track_hash_idx (track_hash=?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the join to `albums` (again).
The `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax provides actually an implicit join of `albums` to `best`:

```
UPDATE albums AS a
SET alias = b.bid 
FROM best AS b
WHERE a.track_hash = b.track_hash
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Why did I experience no slowdown when doing a select, though? Also, why is using an explicit join instead of an implicit one causing such a massive slowdown?

Comment: @Dariush the SELECT statement is correct: it joins the table to the cte. The UPDATE statement you  used had a redundant join to albums: you joined albums to the join of albums and the cte.